# Show recently added record at top in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

There is a image upload functionality in my vuejs application.
The image upload works good and the uploaded recorded is also displayed.
But this recently added record get displayed at last in my list. On page refresh it appears at top.

I want to show the recently uploaded image at top as soon as after successful upload.

I have been trying really hard for this since 2 days and couldn't find the solution.

Please help. Vuejs version is 2

Comment: Show a component code and template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically if I'm correct what you want is to push new images to the images array, for this just use [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

something like this

```js
this.images.unshift('url_or_info_of_the_new_image')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you do have an example of code showing you how you could achieve this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-tree-nig54?file=/src/App.vue

Essentially, the most interesting part is `this.initialArray = [this.newValue, ...this.initialArray]`.

Also, depends on what you've tried until now but keep in mind the few caveats JavaScript does have with VueJS v2: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays